# Полный список #include директив

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Существует ли полный список #include директив, которые нужно подключить, чтобы можно было использовать все операторы c++, дело в том что что я изучая чужой исходный код натыкался на такие операторы как: "strchr", "com", "strcpy", "BOOL", "UINT", "HMENU" и тд, если да, то можете ли вы его предоставить?

Comment: Ну начнем... `#include "a.h"` `#include "b.h"` `#include "c.h"` `#include "d.h"` - ну, и так далее, пока не переберете все слова любой длины :) Потом, потренировавшись, можно переходить к `#define`... Может, вы все-таки вопрос зададите *иначе*?

Comment: Аргументом директивы `#include` является путь к заголовочному *файлу*.

Comment: Вот тут полный список стандартных: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header

Answer (score 0):

Списка всех точно нет.

Но есть список стандарных(?? если можно так их наззвать)

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_C%2B%2B

Каждый может написать свой #include "sometext"

```
Стандартная библиотека языка программирования C++
Ввод-вывод:

fstream
iomanip
ios
iosfwd
iostream (ostream, istream)
sstream
streambuf
Многопоточность:

atomic (C++11)
condition_variable (C++11)
future (C++11)
mutex (C++11)
shared_mutex (C++14)
thread (C++11)
Прочие:

algorithm
bitset
chrono (C++11)
codecvt (C++11)
complex
exception
functional
initializer_list (C++11)
iterator
limits
locale
memory
new
numeric
random (C++11)
ratio (C++11)
regex (C++11)
stdexcept
string
system_error (C++11)
tuple (C++11)
typeindex (C++11)
typeinfo
type_traits (C++11)
utility
valarray
Стандартная библиотека шаблонов
Последовательные контейнеры:

array (C++11)
deque
forward_list (C++11)
list
vector, vector<bool>
Ассоциативные контейнеры:

map
set
multimap
multiset
unordered_map (C++11)
unordered_set (C++11)
unordered_multimap (C++11)
unordered_multiset (C++11)
Контейнеры-адаптеры:

stack
priority_queue
queue
Стандартная библиотека языка программирования Си
cassert
cctype
cerrno
cfenv (C++11)
cfloat
cinttypes (C++11)
ciso646
climits
clocale
cmath
csetjmp
csignal
cstdarg
cstdbool (C++11)
cstddef
cstdint (C++11)
cstdio
cstdlib
cstring
ctgmath (C++11)
ctime
cuchar (C++11)
cwchar
cwctype
```

и это не полный список

Comment: Во-первых, не рекомендуется давать ответ, в котором только URL - см. правила сайта, а во-вторых, по этому URL *далеко* не полный список стандартных заголовочных файлов...